# What rules apply to closing heredoc strings?

Tags: php

I have always thought that heredoc strings shall end with a very clean line, e.g. `EOD;`... nothing else shall exist on that line - no indentation, no spaces before or after, etc...

The PHP heredoc documentation says the same: "*It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon*"

But it seems that it's not that important at all. Take a look at the examples below. The last heredoc-text generates syntax error (but not on the closing `EOD;`). The first two examples works fine.

My question is: Is it allowed to indent the closing heredoc identifier, as in the second example? This makes the code look better IMHO. Or, are there situations where an indented closing identifier will result in unexpected behaviour?

```
<?php
function talk_to_me() {
    // Example 1: The closing EOD; is "clean" - no indentation and nothing after... just like it should. Right?
    $text = <<<EOD
        Hello World
EOD;   

    echo "<div> $text </div>";


    // Example 2: The closing EOD; is indented. It shouldn't be allowed, but it works fine (?)
    $text = <<<EOD
        How are you?
        EOD;   

    echo "<div> $text </div>";


    // Example 3: The 'Bye bye' text is not indented... THAT line generates an error, but not the indented EOD;
    // Syntax error says: "Invalid body indentation level (expecting an indentation level of at least 8)"   
    $text = <<<EOD
    Bye bye!
        EOD;

    echo "<div> $text </div>";
}

talk_to_me();  
/* 
   If the "Bye bye" is indented correctly this will output:

   Hello World
   How are you?
   Bye bye!
*/
?>
```

Comment: For php 7.3 - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php

Comment: Great work on keeping the documentation up-to-date…

Comment: @NigelRen Perfect answer! Thanks!